# Arithmetic problem solving

Tags: problem-solving

Two girls collect stamps. Between the two they have 67 stamps. One of them has 8 stamps more than the other. How many stamps does each one have?

HELP please this is for my daughter. I didn't get how to find the answer.

Comment: let x. so x+8+x=67 One has x and the other has x+8

Comment: I try that but then x=29.5 and it couldn't be possible to have that amount of stamps

Comment: Yes, if you expected integer, question is not correct.

Comment: That the answer with the given information. Is it possible that there is an error in the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no answer if the stamps are not divisible.  As the difference $8$ is even, they either both have an even number or both have an odd number.  The sum of two numbers of the same parity is even, so they cannot have a total of an odd number of stamps unless you can divide a stamp in half.

I agree that you are not expected to split stamps, so you should complain to the problem setter.

Answer (score 1):

As other people said, it can't be a integer, since you can express that equation as, for the first girl $x+8$ and fot the other as $x$ and since you know that they have 67 stamps, so you can express that statement as $2x+8=67$ $\implies$ $2x=59$ and this $\implies$ $x=\frac{59}{2}$ maybe the problem was not written right